# How to add an email address field in shipment information in virtuemart 2?

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

We have a website that sells gift certificates. We use vm2 as extension for ecommerce functionality of the website. I want to use the shipment information as the recipient information of the gift certificate. But the form in shipment info does not have an email address field. That's why I want to add that field. How can I do it?

I've been trying to find it but only found adding field in the joomla registration page. By the way I am using joomla 2.5.16 and virtuemart 2.0.26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using VM2.x Shipping and billing section already have email fields.

You can simply add or remove fields using below options.

```
Login to Admin -> Components -> Virtuemart -> Configuration - > Shopper Fields ->
```

It already have many fields that may disabled or hide just activate those or create new and set to visible on Shipping form.

Hope its helps..

Comment: Thank you so much Sir! Big help to us. :)